# CSS alignment - <h3> <span>

Tags: css, alignment

I have the following fiddle - here I am trying to align the 'click' and `<h3>` in the same line
I am facing 2 issues here - 
when the `h3` content is too long it is pushing 'click' - 
and on click when it shows the content it is moving sideways. Any ideas on how to acheive this - new to CSS.

Tried giving `display:inline` to `<h3>` but that did not help in this scenario.
http://jsfiddle.net/92spd439/

```js
$('#ttt a#iimarrow').css({
  cursor: "pointer"
}).on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: none;
}
#ttt {
  float: right;
}
a#iimarrow {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3><a> tdhfkjshdfhsdfsdflkshdlflskfjl</a><h3>
<span id="ttt">
    <a id="iimarrow">click</a>
<ul>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    </ul> 
    </span>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question, rather than keeping it in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is actually the `h3` element which defaults to a `display: block;`. So if you just remove `a#iimarrow{display:inline-block;}` (since `a` tags default to `display: inline;` as **@mikelt21** pointed out) and add the CSS below, then your problem will be fixed.

```
h3 {
   display: inline;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/92spd439/6/)

Comment: you can also remove the `a#iimarrow` style altogether since I believe anchor tags are `display: inline` by default.

Comment: Here the main issue I am facing is when <h3> content is very big it should not push 'click' to second line how can I achieve this?

Comment: Also not sure why - onclick -'click' is moving..?

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/92spd439/16/) might be what you are looking for.

What I did was add `float:left` to the first `<a>`.

As following:

```
<h3>
   <a style="float:left"> tdhfkjshdfhsdfsdflkshdlflskfjl</a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by placing the right-floated `<a>` element ahead of the `<h3>` in the HTML:

```js
$('#ttt a#iimarrow').css({
  cursor: "pointer"
}).on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: none;
}
#ttt {
  float: right;
}
a#iimarrow {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ttt"><a id="iimarrow">click</a>
  <ul>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h3><a>tdhfkjshdfhsdfsdflkshdlflskfjl</a><h3>
```

Note that a `<span>` cannot contain the block-level `<ul>` element, so I've used a `<div>` in place of that, otherwise the only change is rearranging so the `<div>` (`#ttt`) comes ahead of the `<h3>`.